# Errors showed up when i did flutter clean on flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, release, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload my flutter app to Google Play Console(.aab). But when i uploaded the file, there's an error says that the project file is still in debug mode and needed to change to release mode. I've followed the instructions to change it to the release from from flutter dev website and it still showed the same error when i uploaded it to Google Play Console. Then i see in stackoverflow that i need to do the flutter clean in my project and i did it, but when the flutter clean finished, there are a lot of errors show up in my code and i don't understand why.

i'm really new in flutter and have only been doing this for 1 month, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'invalidate cache and restart' you can usually solve this kind of issues.